# Any other sport with draws like cricket?

Tags: rules, cricket

In Test and first-class cricket, to win you need to do two things: outscore your opponent and bowl them out twice. If you only manage to outscore them, but fail to cause their last innings to come to an end, the game will end in a draw, no matter how large your lead.

Are there any other sports where you need to achieve two different objectives like that within a set period of time (Or some other limitation on the duration of the game) to win, barring which it becomes a draw?

Comment: FYI: You don't need to bowl them out. Technically you can win the match even without taking a single wicket out of 20!

Comment: If I just consider "draw"..then Chess.

Answer (score 1):

After five years without a definitive answer, I'm going to go out on a not very big limb here and say that there isn't another major sport which has the same "draw" type characteristics as (first class) cricket.